# Number of results from CSE do not match google total results number

Tags: google-custom-search

In Google Custom Search Engine if I make a search like this:

> https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={$apikey}&q=####KEYWORD#####&cref={$cref}&alt=json

with my $apikey and my $cref I get a json results that do not match with the results of google via browser.
I've configured my search engine to search all the web as described [here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/customsearch/thread?tid=56c0bd92dda351b7&hl=en) but I've noticed that many results are missing, for example the ones from forums.
Is there a way to specify to CSE to search also the forums? I want to use the same results as google classic search.

Comment: +1 - I've got the same problem. Even previewing a query in the CSE control panel and running the same query in vanilla google give radically different results. My only guess so far is that it's using location information to tailor results and my server's getting classified differently

Comment: I think it's filtering the results by date.  If I play with the left column search tools on google.com and filter to show only the last years records it shows me quite the same records as CSE. So. I think that my CSE is filtering results showing me only the last year results. The question is: how can I add "Any time" results?

Comment: Well, I've found out that the CSE tool uses the Julian Calendar for dates... http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-ways-to-search-by-date-on-google/ (Point #6). If you find a way to embed the date in the query, please let me know.